# How to Get Total Page Count for a Report Using CrystalReportViewer?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, reportviewer, reportviewer2008

I am using **Crystal Report 2008 with C#**, have a WinForm and want to show **Page N of M** to user in a **Label**. 
How can I impelemnt that?
I searched and couldn't find any straightforward answer.
**NOTICE**: *I used a CrystalReportViewer1 and CRGeneral.rpt*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way works well But i think I can Find better solution:

```
        viewer.ShowLastPage();
        string TotalPage = viewer.GetCurrentPageNumber().ToString();
        viewer.ShowFirstPage(); 
        pageNo.Text = viewer.GetCurrentPageNumber() + " of " + TotalPage;
```

Any Better Answer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a better answer

```
viewer.pageView = (PageView)viewer.Controls[0];

var pagecount = viewer.pageView.GetLastPageNumber();
```

Source [Take Control of Crystal Report Viewer](http://blog.irm.se/blogs/eric/archive/2005/06/06/389.aspx)

Comment: When using SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.CrystalReportsViewer you have to dig a little deeper through the ViewerCore to access the functions shown in this and many other code examples e.g. viewer.ViewerCore.GetLastPageNumber()