# Page Count in Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0, crystal-reports

This is relevent to the question [How to Get Total Page Count for a Report Using CrystalReportViewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306985/how-to-get-total-page-count-for-a-report-using-crystalreportviewer)

I am using `CrystalReportViewer` in my `win-from` application.(Crystal Report 2011)

But is there any propper way of obtaining total number of pages that report contains?
Seems like the CrystalReportViewer doesn't contain any property showing the page count. I did look around in google as well. Seems there is not any answer for this problem.

Any help is appreciate !!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, found an answer

```
Dim a As PageView = ReportViewer.Controls(0)
Dim count = a.GetLastPageNumber()
```

Source [Take Control of Crystal Report Viewer](http://blog.irm.se/blogs/eric/archive/2005/06/06/389.aspx)